# MongoDB no ar na AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-aws, mongoose

Preciso de uma ajuda, não encontrei nada prático e exato no google, eu tenho um backend com node e utilizando o mongoose, e eu consigo rodar local tranquilamente, pois no CMD eu executo o comando 'mongod', e o meu mongo local fica no ar, e eu conecto pelo cmd no meu sv na aws, e só tenho acesso a linha de comando, se eu executo 'mongod' da certo, mas se eu fecho a conexao com o sv, ele vai cair, como deixar ele ativo o tempo todo? tipo um pm2 com node.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa iniciar o mongo com a flag `--fork`. A flag fork requer uma outra flag para indicar onde os logs serão registrados (já que não vai ser mais no proprio console).

Exemplo:

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

Ao invés de `--logpath` você também pode usar a flag `--syslog` que manda todos os logs para o sistema de logs do próprio sistema operacional (essa flag não funciona no windows).

Dessa maneira quando você se desconectar da instância na AWS o mongo continua rodando.